# get all class name in css file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got css file like this :

```
let string =

    .papa, .aka {
        color:red
    }
    .mama .ok {
        color:blue
    }

    div .chacha{
        transition: opacity 0.2s;
    } .sasa {
        background:url(home.png)
    }
```

I want to fetch all the class name in the file and put in array. Expected result :

```
[.papa, .aka, .mama, .ok, .chacha, .sasa]
```

My try :

```
let pattern = /(?:[\.]{1})([a-zA-Z_]+[\w-_]*)(?:[\s\.\{\>#\:]{1})/igm

let match = pattern.exec(string);

console.log(match);
```

I only got `[.papa]`.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/5894241 You need to invoke `regex.exec` multiple times to get subsequent capturing groups.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [string.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
let string =
`
    .papa, .aka {
        color:red
    }
    .mama .ok {
        color:blue
    }

    div .chacha {
        transition: opacity 0.2s;
    } .sasa {
        background:url(home.png)
    }
`
var arr = string.match(/(?:[\.]{1})([a-zA-Z_]+[\w-_]*)(?:[\s\.\,\{\>#\:]{0})/igm);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: There is case it doesn't, I made an update to string, class .papa is missing now

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [];
match.input.replace(pattern, function(match, g1, g2) { arr.push(g1); });
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, please explain what you have done to solve the problem. Code-only answers are usually not helpful to other readers, and tend to attract downvotes. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)